# Failed install apache2 in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apache2, owncloud-server

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
Suggested packages:
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
Recommended packages:
  ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,308 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,562 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-bin.
(Reading database ... 83701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-bin_2.4.27-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.27-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.27-2ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.27-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up apache2-bin (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (234-2ubuntu12.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.27-2ubuntu3) ...
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status apache2.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
**●** apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: **failed (Result: exit-code)** since Thu 2017-11-16 05:00:16 UTC; 14ms ago
  Process: 4690 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1107 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CPU: 18ms



Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest apachectl[4690]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest apachectl[4690]: Action 'start' failed.
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest apachectl[4690]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 16 05:00:16 vultr.guest systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I don't know how to fix it.Please help me! I am a freshman.
I just want to install owncloud.

Comment: This ` apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is your problem. Please do `cat -n /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and paste that into your question so we can see the syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Install the package libapache2-mod-php7.0

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

or disable the PHP7 module by running

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still can't install Owncloud successfully. I will try it again.